# How to interface a thermal printer to an Arduino

Tags: arduino, rs232, ttl, arduino-uno

I've a thermal printer which has TTL, RS232 & a four pin interface. I want to connect it to an Arduino and take printouts with it. It has the following pinouts:

**RS232** & **TTL**

- GND
- TXD
- RXD
- DSR
- DTR

**Another Four Pins Interface**

- LED
- FEED
- ONLINE
- GND

I've tried printing using the serial communication by sending serial print commands from the TX of the Arduino to the RXD of the printer but for some reason it did not work.

How can I connect it to an Arduino and write a program for it?

**Datasheet Links**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F7it7uGA20YBPsqsTllIjLz1V8hDCv9Y/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FKDVJOw3tqIYPo8PN1DfwKDOgMbw3mg6/view?usp=drivesdk

[image: Item Image]

Comment: You find the datasheet

Comment: I have what seems to be a data sheet..what exactly should I look for in it? It only mentions about some ESC codes. Not much about pin descriptions.

Comment: Serial ports are usually RS232 *OR* TTL.  As these specs indicate polarity and voltage ranges.  You need be be certain what your printer supports on this interface, as it's also possible to damage fragile components if you get it wrong.  Link the datasheets.

Comment: One issue you could have is your voltage to your printer is too low. I've had issues trying to print at lower voltages like 5v. If you have the one I'm thinking of, I would recommend printing at 9v.

Comment: Look at the datasheet if the interface is TTL or RS232. If RS232, then you need RS232 tranceiver between a standard RS232 device and TTL level IO pins of Arduino.

Comment: It is both TTL and RS233.

Comment: "It is both TTL and RS23[2]"  How?  Provide documents.  Also sketch out, and share, your wiring connections once you provide the documents.

Comment: I simply connected the TX of the Arduino Uno to the RXD of the thermal printer and connected both the GNDs. I'm supplying 7.5v and 9v and 2.4A.

Comment: Questions on the *usage* of products are not on topic.  Your reasonable courses of action are to study the data sheets and determine necessary conditions - pay attention for example to anything about online mode, or selection of interfaces; or else to find documention of someone's successful usage of this product, or else to ask the manufacturer for assistance.  This is also not a place to ask for help in finding resources elsewhere online.

Comment: The provided links do not work (permission errors).

Comment: Please view again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I couldn't find anything related to this particular model.

Comment: @bunker89320 I've given it 7.5v, 9v and 2.4A.

Comment: Maybe you should see what you can learn from writeups on other models

Comment: Maybe: http://tronixstuff.blogspot.com/2011/07/tutorial-arduino-and-thermal-printer.html (be weary of dead links) and https://sites.google.com/site/tronixstuff/home/arduino-tutorial-series-files will get you going.  See **example38p1.ino**

Comment: What libraries are you using and where did you buy it from?

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I'm trying these..

Comment: @bunker89320 I'm not using any libraries only inbuilt serial communication. I purchased it from a local electronics distributor in my city.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library). The command set seems similar (for example `Init` is `ESC` + `@`). If anything, you can try to copy fragments of code for a simple printout.

Couple of things to consider:

1. Thermal printers need a stronger power supply. Get an external 9V power supply and connect it to the *printer* (not the Arduino!) - Seems like you did that.
2. Make sure GND on both the printer and board are connected.
3. Make sure the baudrate of the Arduino is compatible with the printer (e.g. `Serial1.begin(19200);`
4. Be patient. Hardware development is an art that fights back. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

you cannot connect RS232 to arduino you must use a RS232 to TTL converter whereby the rs232 goes to the printer and the ttl goes to arduino. Also you must  swap the RX and TX lines at the arduino ,you can purchase the RS232 converter on ebay or amazon they are low cost .IF you connected the arduino directly to the RS232 printer well now you need a new arduino as it will not take RS232 voltage.

Comment: This thermal printer has both an RS-232 and a TTL connector (see [Serial communication connector, page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PeMp.png)). An additional RS-232 converter isn't necessary.

Comment: The circuit board clearly says RS232

Comment: Yes. And the bottom-right connector clearly says TTL. As I said, this thermal printer supports both RS-232 and TTL.

Comment: Ok so use the TTL lines and connect in accordance Rem to swap the Rx/Tx lines at the arduino

Comment: Rem the gro wire

Comment: I think the DSR (data set ready) line has to be gro also check adafruit

Comment: Rem to set the baud rate at the printer and the arduino they must be the same,The last time I had to connect was 3 years ago and it took 2 days to get it working right ,the DSR line gave me hell.